# Consulta relação muito para muitos SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ola, estou com uma duvida para fazer um `select` no `SQL SERVER`. Possuo 3 tabelas. Elas são, **LIVROS, AUTOR** e **LIVRO_AUTOR**. A **LIVRO_AUTOR** possui chave estrangeira do `id` da **LIVROS** E **AUTOR**. Preciso fazer um `select` que retorne todos os livros com autores nascidos no Brasil (esse campo tem na tabela autor). Fiquei pensando algum tempo nesse problema, me parece simples. mas ate agora não achei como fazer funcionar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jhow tem mais de uma maneira de resolver seu problema , uma delas seria :

```
      select titulo from livros inner join livro_autor on livros.id = livro_autor.fk_livro 
      inner join autor on autor.id = livro_autor.fk_autor 
      where autor.pais = 'Brasil'group by livros.id , livros.titulo
```

Answer (score 2):

Olá, não conheço a estrutura de suas tabelas, então vou tentar te ajudar...

```
select livros.titulo,
       autor.pais
From livros inner join livro_autor
On livros.objectid = livro_autor.objectidlivro
Inner join autor
On autor.objectid = livro_autor.objectidautor
where autor.pais = 'Brasil'
```

`livros.titulo` deverá ser substituído pelo nome da coluna em que está a informação do título na sua tabela livros. (`Livros.nome_da_coluna`)

`autor.pais` deverá ser substituído pelo nome da coluna onde está a informação do país na tabela autor. (`Autor.nome_da_coluna`)

Nos inner join, onde está `objectid` você deve substituir pelo nome da coluna onde estão as informações que se relacionam nas suas tabelas, inicialmente na tabela livros, depois na `livro_autor` que se relaciona com livros. Depois a coluna da tabela autor que se relaciona com a tabela `livro_autor`.

Espero ter te ajudado, caso tenha ficado meio confuso, informe os nomes dessas colunas que monto novamente o script correto.

Avise se deu certo.

Comment: Olá, Guilherme. Seja bem-vindo! Quando a pergunta que você pretende responder não possui detalhes suficientes para dar uma resposta satisfatória, é preferível esperar esclarecimentos do autor. Você poderá comentar para pedir isso você mesmo assim que ganhar um pouco mais de reputação. Além disso, use as ferramentas de formatação para separar código de texto, para que fique mais fácil distinguir. Dá pra ter uma noção de como está ficando a resposta olhando a prévia logo abaixo da caixa de edição.